# How to store different classes in a vector?

Tags: c++

I have two classes with different member type. I wanted to store these two different classes in a vector and then try to print out all values inside of that object. I written the following code:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Box
{
public:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Lox
{
public:
    int m_number;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto v = std::vector<std::variant<Box, Lox>>{"Milad", 30};
    v.push_back(Lox{ 21 });
    v.push_back(Box{ "ROme" });
    assert(std::get<Lox>(v[0]).m_number == 21);
    assert(std::get<Box>(v[1]).m_name == "ROme");

    return 0;
}
```

These are my problems with MSVC compiler:

1. 'variant': is not a member of 'std'
2. 'variant': undeclared identifier
3. 'Box': illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: Are you compiling with C++17?

Comment: This is what *polymorphism* is for

Comment: Your assert use wrong index, as initial size would be 2, so `Lox{21}` would be at index 2

Comment: You need to be explicit in construction `{"Milad", 30}` -> `{Box{"Milad"}, Lox{30}}`, [working code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e437947306035d9a).

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Yes, exactly. That's why OP is trying to use the excellent `std::variant`, the closest thing we have in C++ to proper algebraic data types.

Comment: The first complaint (and therefore the one you should be focused on) is about `std::variant`. So write a simpler program that just uses `std::variant` and see if that works. I'll bet `vector` has nothing to do with the problem.